# How to use native c++ template class in c++/cli

Tags: c#, c++, managed

I have a native c++ dll  which contains some templates classes. And I need this dll in my c# code.
So I am using managed c++ for the c++ dll in order to use it in the c# code, but I have a big problem on how using the template classes in .Net.
Please if you guys have some solutions to this, it will very helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. read [C++ instantiate template class from DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138360/c-instantiate-template-class-from-dll) to make sure you're not falling down a common rabbit hole.
2. Read about IntPtr and [Interoperability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx)
3. Try putting it all together, and then post a new question which has a specific problem.